# In timeline, retain the toggle format, when switching between the event filters

Tags: feature-request, timeline

In the timeline page, when I switched in between the “Hide vote summaries” and “Show vote summaries” options, the selected toggle format is not retained, it is always displayed with the default format when switched.

For example: By pressing the "toggle format", I can see the timeline entries in the yyyy-MM-dd format. But if I switch to other event filter option, the toggled format is not retained.

GIF for the same:

> [image: GIF]

So once the toggle format is selected, can this be retained in between switching the options until the page is closed?

Comment: Is this a feature request, or should it be considered a bug? Might get more attention if labeled the latter.